# not able to access my new form in any of the other form or class

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

i am new in C#, i am working on a project using C# in Visual Studio, i have already 8 to 9 forms in my project, today when i created one more form named frmUserBio, it's not accessible in other forms, whenever namespace of the forms and program.cs file is same, every thing looks perfect but i am still not able to access it, writting below some code of my program.cs and frmUserBio form Code,

Program.cs Code:

```
namespace SurveyBuilder
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
```

frmUserBio.cs code:

```
namespace SurveyBuilder.Forms
{
    public partial class frmUserBio : Form
    {
        public frmUserBio()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void frmUserBio_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         //
        }                   
    }
}
```

i am want to open frmUserBio form in another form using

```
frmUserBio frm = new frmUserBio();
frm.Show();
```

but i am not able to access frmUserBio Form here....

and the form in which i want to access frmUserBio is name frmUserList, it's code is given below

frmUserList.cs Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace SurveyBuilder
{
    public partial class frmUserList : Form
    {
        public frmUserList()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: You should be able to do this, post code of your another form, maybe it's in another namespace ?

Comment: Error message? Namespace?

Comment: yes the other form in which i want to acees is name frmUserList and it's starting code is:using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace SurveyBuilder
{
    public partial class frmUserList : Form
    {
        public frmUserList()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Dispose();
        }

Comment: @AyeshaNoor edit your question and don't post large code in comment :)

Comment: it's of same namespace SurveyBuilder

Comment: It is not. The `namespace` of your form is `SurveyBuilder.Forms`, not `SurveyBuilder`. It's pretty obvious

Comment: @AndreyGordeev if i change my frmUserBio namespace to SurveyBuilder then it give error on intializeComponenet(); and says the name intializeComponenet() doesn't exist in the current context....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should mention your form namespace in *using*

```
using SurveyBuilder.Forms; // <- Namespace where frmUserBio class is declared
...
frmUserBio frm = new frmUserBio();
frm.Show();
```

or use the *full form*:

```
SurveyBuilder.Forms.frmUserBio frm = new SurveyBuilder.Forms.frmUserBio();
frm.Show();
```

Comment: it work on code but when i compile it it give error "Error 1 The type or namespace name 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace 'SurveyBuilder' (are you missing an assembly reference?) C:\Users\ayesha\Desktop\Project Survey Builder\SurveyBuilder\SurveyBuilder\Forms\frmUserList.cs 10 21 SurveyBuilder
"

Comment: If frmUserBio.cs and frmUserList.cs belong to separate assemblies, you should add reference in the frmUserList.cs's assembly to frmUserBio.cs's assembly (the easiest way, IMHO, to do this is to use Solution Explorer)

Answer (score 0):

`frmUserBio` is defined in the `SurveyBuilder.Forms` namespace, so you need to add a `using` for it:

```
using SurveyBuilder.Forms;
```

Comment: it work on code but when i compile it it give error "Error 1 The type or namespace name 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace 'SurveyBuilder' (are you missing an assembly reference?) C:\Users\ayesha\Desktop\Project Survey Builder\SurveyBuilder\SurveyBuilder\Forms\frmUserList.cs 10 21 SurveyBuilder "

Comment: Did you define frmUserBio in a separate project?

Answer (score 0):

Check all forms namespace should be same in form.designer.cs if not select the namespace right click > refactor>Rename as main form namespace.